# hfeed CSS class in Twentyeleven Theme

Tags: themes, css

The twentyeleven theme has hfeed class attached with the main container #page. I could not find any definition of hfeed in style.css. Does it have any purpose or its just a random class name given?

Answer (score 3):

A microformat, part of the [hAtom spec](http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom) - primarily to give "meaning" to machines.

Answer (score 2):

hfeed is class not particularly used for styling, that class is used by search engine bots to identify your site as a blog.

Not sure about this but I think It tells the bot (Suppose Google Crawler) that the  site is not a static page, the content within hfeed class-wrap gets updated frequently, Bots should re-crawl for new content.